# Trouble finding the nouns for a paragraph

Tags: nouns

So, i am trying to find 3 key nouns, 3 pronouns that refer to them and synonyms that are substitutes for them. These are for a paragraph in school, but I am really in trouble with it. This is the paragraph and is called "A Mardi Gras Custom":

> (1)  “Throw me something, mister,” is the customary plea for a Mardi
>   Gras “throw.”  (2)  In the final days of Mardi Gras -- the season of
>   parties, parades, and revelry that precedes the Christian period of
>   fasting and penance called Lent -- crowds of spectators line the
>   streets of New Orleans.  (3)  They hope to catch a Mardi Gras souvenir
>   tossed from parading floats.  (4)  Mardi Gras organizations called
>   “krewes” build the floats and sponsor the parades, and while cruising
>   along parade routes, costumed krewe members throw plastic trinkets to
>   the crowds below.  (5)  The trinkets, which are called “throws,”
>   consist of bead necklaces, coins, cups, toys, Frisbees, and figurines
>   stamped with the krewe’s symbol or the parade theme.  (6)  Mardi Gras
>   throws are big business for the companies that supply them.  (7) 
>   Krewe members spend an average of $800 on them, and some spend much
>   more.  (8)  By far the most treasured of the Mardi Gras mementos are
>   gaudy bead necklaces.  (9)  Originally made of glass, they are now
>   made of plastic (Roach, 2001).

The only noun that I found that has a pronoun ("They", in the third sentence) but I can't find a synonym for it, is "spectators" (second sentence). I don't need you to find me the answers.

*I just want to **understand** how to find them.*

Comment: If I had to do this exercise, I would highlight all of the pronouns in the text then try to find their nouns.

Answer (score 1):

An indicator for a synonym is a statement like "ABC, also known as XYZ", or "the huge American city called the Big Apple" - eg. when something is first described by its properties and then is being given a (synonymous) "name".

When looking for pronouns that replace nouns, they often replace nouns in *earlier* sentences. "I ate **an Apple**. And **it** tasted good." So look beyound sentence boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

@ColleenV answered in a comment:

> If I had to do this exercise, I would highlight all of the pronouns in the text then try to find their nouns.